# Getting textarea html to apply styles given in the tinyMCE editor, database issue?

Tags: html, sql, tinymce, textarea, plaintext

I have a tinyMCE text editor which works. The only thing is that the text which I input to the editor is stored and retrieved as so:

```
<p><strong>the first line</strong></p> <p><em>the second line</em></p>
```

Instead of:

**the first line**

*the second line*

I think the problem is something to do with the type of field I'm using in my database. Should it be VARCHAR, TEXT or something else? Could someone give me some pointers and a resolution possibly??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

do you have `encoding: xml` set in your configuration? Better yet, let's see your configuration.

Comment: <?php

     /* Database Connection */

     $sDbHost = 'xxxx';
     $sDbName = 'xxxx';
     $sDbUser = 'xxxxx';
     $sDbPwd = 'xxxxx';

     $dbConn = mysql_connect ($sDbHost, $sDbUser, $sDbPwd) or die ('MySQL connect failed. ' . mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db($sDbName,$dbConn) or die('Cannot select database. ' . mysql_error());

     ?>

Comment: he is talking about your tinymce configuration